# storyboard unwind segue not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am a new developer. I am working on a simple project using a storyboard in Xcode 7.

The entry point is a nav controller. The nav controller has a relationship "root view controller" to the next view controller (tableview controller A).

A has a `prepareForSegue` that is triggered by a bar button item in A's navigation bar.

After some work, A segues to a uiviewController (B), which segues to controller C (tableview controller) via a click on a label in the view.

All of the forward segues work fine, as does the unwind segue from C to B.

The problem is this: if I embed controller B in a nav controller, I get an exception that there is no interface for a setItem method in B. If I don't embed B in a nav controller, I don't get this error, but then I have to add a navigation item to the B scene.

I add a Done bar button item to the navigation item left bar button (or right bar button), and wire this up to the unwind segue to A, and the B scene shows "segue to Exit" and the unwind segue in A was correctly connected when I dragged from the Done button to Exit icon in B's navigation item.

But when I click on the Done button, nothing happens. A breakpoint in the unwind segue in A never gets executed. I don't understand: 1) why embedding B in a nav controller prevents access to the setItem property (it is declared in B's header) 2) why the B to A unwind segue doesn't execute. The strange thing is that I originally built this project using the Apple Master-Slave template and had none of these problems. I am only changing it because I don't intend to run it on an iPad, thus no need for the split controller that gets set up by the Master-Slave template.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't embed B in a Nav controller anyway because A is already in a Nav controller, so B will be under that Nav controller.  Unwind segues are actually determined at runtime. I suggest you review this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html and see if it helps

Comment: I have read that document but it doesn't answer either of these questions. I found another post that said the nav controller actually gets the unwind segue so you have to do a custom nav controller to handle it. I implemented it and things are now working. But I still don't have an answer to the two questions I asked. Thanks, though!

Comment: My guess on your first question is that you were trying to access the item property via the destination view controller in prepareForSegue but if B is in a navigation controller then the destination vc is the navigation controller - B would be the nav controllers root view controller